# Responsive images in Bootstrap 4 slider

Tags: images, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a Bootstrap 4 slider in progress at https://filathlos.imagewize.com/ . When I add images of a 0.75 ratio like 2000x1500 they display and resize well. 3000x2000 works too. This with them being loaded with:

`the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'img-responsive responsive--full', 'title' => 'Feature image']);`

It seems to show the images the way I cropped them in WordPress or not and then load them with file dimensions that vary from image to image.

When I use `add_image_size( 'b4-slider', 2000, 1500);` or `add_image_size( 'b4-slider', 2000, 1500, true);` because I am like, let's automate setting the proper size for these babies.. they are no longer responsive. They get squashed when I shrink the browser window size.

How is this possible?

Comment: Do see in CSS now that image attributes are being ignored: `img[Attributes Style] { width: 3001px; height: 2000px;}` This by my own set width 100% and height auto for the slider image. And the full sized images loaded do have the ratio I gave them. Some the same as the add_image height I added. So why does that not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I figured it out. I changed the thumbnail AND removed the needed class img-responsive to apply responsive dimensions. Once I kept those all was fine. –